Restrictions on User Defined Functions: Unresolved reference binding
I'm trying to understand if it is possibe to extend a new column with the output of a user defined function.
I would like to achieve the same as the following:
print k='8.8.8.8'
| extend l = geo_info_from_ip_address(k)

In my user defined function I'm contacting an API with a value stated in a parameter and returning a tabular output. The documentation on User Defined Functions seem to suggest there are some restrictions on achieving this because the parameter would depend on the row-context. Is it possible to overcome this restriction in any way?
The error message I'm getting in particular is:
Semantic error: Unresolved reference binding: 'IPAddress'

edit: sample query as requested below
let f = (IP:string) {
let uri=strcat('https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/ip_addresses/', IP);
let header=dynamic({'x-apikey':'x'});
let request = (uri:string, headers:dynamic) {
evaluate http_request(uri, headers)
};
request(uri, header)
| evaluate bag_unpack(ResponseBody, 'rbody_')
| mv-expand rbody_data 
| evaluate bag_unpack(rbody_data)
| where isnotempty(attributes)
| evaluate bag_unpack(attributes)
| project-away ResponseHeaders, ResponseStatusCode, ResponseReasonPhrase
| extend IP = IP
| extend whois_date = column_ifexists("whois_date", "")
| extend whois = column_ifexists("whois", "")
| extend last_modification_date = column_ifexists("last_modification_date", "")
| extend last_analysis_date = column_ifexists("last_analysis_date", "")
| extend last_analysis_stats = column_ifexists("last_analysis_stats", "")
| extend as_owner = column_ifexists("as_owner", "")
| extend asn = column_ifexists("asn", "")
| extend ['network'] = column_ifexists("['network']", "")
| project tostring(as_owner)
};
SigninLogs
| extend l = geo_info_from_ip_address(IPAddress)

| extend k = f(IPAddress)        
// Result: Semantic error: Unresolved reference binding: 'IPAddress'
| extend k = f('8.8.8.8')   
// Result: Tabular expression is not expected in the current context
| extend k = toscalar(f('8.8.8.8'))
// Result: works as intended. But does not work for each row
| extend k = toscalar(f(IPAddress))
// Result: 'toscalar' operator: Failed to resolve table or scalar expression named 'IPAddress'


Do you want to add the column returned by the user defined function to your table?

Can you provide your sample input and expected output?

Yes, I would like to achieve the same as in the kql snippet above.
No, I can't provide the API call because it contains my token, which is why I'm asking on a general basis. As for the expected output - same as in the kql snippet above.

If K is a constant and your table will be generated in a single call, why not you store the result in a table and join that with your first table?

K will not be a constant, that was just a simple example. Here is a better one:
SigninLogs | project IPAddress | take 5 | extend geo = geo_info_from_ip_address(IPAddress)

So, you need to pass each row from one column and generate the required column rows based on input column rows. But for this, the function should also return a row as output like this sample https://i.imgur.com/l8vBhAG.png, so that the result column will be generated. But you are saying it's returning tabular values. So, how are you gonna handle that? Correct me if I am wrong.

That snippet is similar to what I want to achieve, yes, but it doesn't work for my API call. It gives me the error message above. And yes, you are right, it does not make sense for me to extend a column with a tabular output from a function, but I could rewrite the function to return a single json column instead, as in the geo_info_from_ip_address(IPAddress). see picture https://imgur.com/opTudki

Can you add the above code as text in the question?

Can you provide expected output with your structure with sample values? and the JSON column structure with sample values returned by your function?

Added the query and some different variations on what I'm trying to achieve. The third example with | extend k = toscalar(f('IPAddress')) shows the expected output. How to achieve that for each row when input varies? toscalar can't be used for that, see the fourth example above.

I talked with a member of the Kusto team regarding this. He managed to boil the question down to how I would like to use the http_request function and the realisation that Kusto is imposing a restriction on the usage of the function, see the following sample code and error message.
SigninLogs
| take 10
| project IPAddress
| extend uri = strcat("https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/ip_addresses/", IPAddress)
| extend header = dynamic({'x-apikey':'xx'})
| evaluate http_request(uri, header)

Yields the error message:
evaluate http_request(): the following error(s) occurred while evaluating the output schema: The 'http_request' plugin's argument 'uri' must be a constant.

Why does the uri need to be a constant? How can I make a HTTP request where the uri depends on the value of a column?
